# trying to load a certain number of objects to stage, failing miserably

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I commented my code below to reflect what I am attempting to do here. Flash is throwing me a 1084 error at the moment but I cannot spot my issue. I expect that it is something to do with the `this['circle'+i]` statement.

```
var boxOne = new box();
stage.addChild(boxOne);
boxOne.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
boxOne.y = stage.stageHeight/2; //This far is fine, no issues.

boxOne.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,spawn)

function spawn() { //Spawn function called by MouseEvent
 for (var i:int = 0;i==5;i++) { //For a total of 5 times
  var this['circle'+i] = new circle(); //Make a new circle object
  stage.addChild(this['circle'+i]); //Add it to the stage
  this['circle'+i].x = stage.stageWidth / (Math.random()*10); //Set X
  this['circle'+i].y = stage.stageHeight / (Math.random()*10); //Set Y
 }
}
```

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"this" is a keyword, and you're trying to define it as a variable.

You either go object scope

```
this['circle'+i] = new circle();
```

or local scope

```
var c:circle = new circle();
```

or an object scope array/vector (best)

```
var circles:Array = new Array() // (outside the function)
circles[i] = new circle()       // (instead of this['circle'+i] = new circle();)
```

Also, classes go upcase first (*Circle* not *circle*), and you want to loop while *i<5*, not *i==5*

Comment: Perfect, that put me back on the right path and I got my program working. Thank you!